# Rinetd failing to run

Tags: linux, linux-networking

We experienced a power outage, and on reboot I can't seem to get `rinetd` to start. Below is what I get.

```
redirecting to systemctl
rinetd.service - LSB: Start the Internet redirection server rinetd
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rinetd)
          Active: active (exited) since Mon, 24 Jun 2013 12:07:14 +0300; 31s ago
         Process: 5527 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/rinetd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 5571 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/rinetd reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 5545 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rinetd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/rinetd.service
```

Comment: Check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rinetd` start messages seem fine, but maybe during the reboot, a server for ports that `rinetd` is meant to forward has also been started? Like Apache2, a mail server etc..

In such a case, rinetd will appear to start, but will not forward anything. You can detect this situation by finding lots of error messages like these in the `/var/log/rinetd.log` logfile:

```
22/Mar/2013:19:35:47 0.0.0.0 0 (null) 0 0 0 accept-failed -
```

To correct that situation, simply stop the servers in question, then restart `rinetd` (on Debian or Ubuntu) with: `service rinetd restart`. To prevent this from happening again, prevent the interfering servers from starting at boot time, for example with `sysv-rc-conf`.